ValueError: `prune_low_magnitude` can only prune an object of the following types: keras.models.Sequential, keras functional model, keras.layers.Layer
I am trying to implement Kernel Based pruning the script is given below:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, Sequential
from tensorflow_model_optimization.sparsity import keras as sparsity
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load and normalize CIFAR10 dataset
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0

# Define pruning parameters
pruning_params = {
    'pruning_schedule': sparsity.PolynomialDecay(
        initial_sparsity=0.2,  # Start with 20% sparsity
        final_sparsity=0.8,    # End with 80% sparsity
        begin_step=0,          # Begin pruning immediately
        end_step=1000          # End pruning after 1000 steps
    )
}

# Define the model with properly wrapped layers
model = Sequential()

# Add pruned Conv2D layers
model.add(
    sparsity.prune_low_magnitude(
        layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
        **pruning_params
    )
)
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(
    sparsity.prune_low_magnitude(
        layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        **pruning_params
    )
)
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(
    sparsity.prune_low_magnitude(
        layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        **pruning_params
    )
)
model.add(layers.Flatten())

# Add pruned Dense layer
model.add(
    sparsity.prune_low_magnitude(
        layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        **pruning_params
    )
)

# Output layer without pruning
model.add(layers.Dense(10))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model with pruning
callbacks = [sparsity.UpdatePruningStep()]  # Add pruning callback
history = model.fit(
    train_images, train_labels,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=(test_images, test_labels),
    callbacks=callbacks
)

# Evaluate the pruned model
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels, verbose=2)
print(f"Test Accuracy (Kernel-Based Pruning): {test_acc:.2f}")

# Strip pruning for deployment
pruned_model = sparsity.strip_pruning(model)

# Save the pruned model
pruned_model.save("pruned_model.h5")
print("Pruned model saved as 'pruned_model.h5'")

while trying to run the code I am getting the below error!!!

ValueError: prune_low_magnitude can only prune an object of the following types: keras.models.Sequential, keras functional model, keras.layers.Layer, list of keras.layers.Layer. You passed an object of type: Conv2D.

Can anyone please help me with this. Thank You.
I have checked the documentations, But I am confused since I wasn't able to solve it.
